# Check user permission on certificate on Windows 2003/2008 server

Tags: asp.net, windows, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Just want to know if there's a way to check which user(s) has permission on a specific certificate from the (local machine) cert store on windows 2003 & 2008 server.

Answer (score 0):

Have a search for winHttpCertCfg.exe